# PHP Open Web Page

Tags: php

I have a mobile app where I need to verify a successful registration. The user goes through the registration process. If everything is successful, I send them an email with a link to a php page. This is just intended to make sure that a human has initiated the registration process.

All I really want to do with this script is to record that the user is confirmed, and then show them a web page to give them feedback that they are successfully registered. It's this very last thing that I am stuck on. Here's the essence of the process:

Email Content:

`Click here to confirm registration: http://mysite.com/confirm_me.php`

After they click on that, this script runs:

confirm_me.php

```
<?php
    //capture some stuff in the database
    //open a confirmation page
    echo "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/you_are_confirmed.html'></a>";
?>
```

But this last line doesn't do anything. How can I show this page to the user? Thanks!

Comment: maybe if you look into the source you learn that it just did not just did not anything. In any case you should actually read more about what you do, especially in cases like the one you describe where you do a lot and then just wonder about some fundamentals.

Comment: You need to put something before the </a>.  eg:  <a href="...">TEXT TO SHOW</a>

Comment: I've been reading about how to do this for a couple of hours, but I'm stuck. The site that I am referencing in my page is fine if I type it into a browser. But how can I open it from php? I've tried fopen and also href. I can't get either work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is redirect the user once you've updated your database

```
<?php
  Header('Location: you_are_confirmed.html');
  exit;
?>
```